# systemd service file to run a script at the time of shutdown is running at startup instead

Tags: linux, systemd, shutdown, daemon

I am new to writing these service files and I have written a systemd service file by following several blogs in stack and unix overflows.

I have a script which needs to run at the time of shutdown and it requires docker daemon running. The service file looks like this

```
[Unit]
Description=Shutdown script
Before=shutdown.target
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStop=/path/to/script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am trying to automate the creation/enabling of above service (which runs the script) in the startup script of the instance by adding the below in the shell script

```
chmod +x /path/to/script
if [ ! -f "/etc/systemd/system/path.service" ]; then
  cp  file/path.service /etc/systemd/system/path.service
  systemctl daemon-reload
fi
systemctl enable path.service
```

I want this to run at the time of every shutdown, but this is running at the time of startup of the instance. Am I making anything wrong in the above service file?

Answer (score 1):

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

does not run a service on shutdown but on boot-up. You want

```
[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target
```

Comment: Thank you @Hauke Laging, after doing the suggested changes, the systemctl status  for the service shows
`● path.service - Script at shutdown` 
   `Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/path.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)`
   `Active: inactive (dead)`
I checked the script to be run is executable and everything is fine. When I run this service using `systemctl start path.service` its working fine. But through automation its showing inactive(dead) in the status.

Comment: I am doubtful if the `Before=shutdown.target` and `WantedBy=shutdown.target` are conflicting with each and hence the inactive state

Comment: And when did you execute `systemctl start path.service`? After you initiated shutdown? Why would you expect a service to be started which is to be started during shutdown only? `Before=shutdown.target` may not be useful ordering. I am not familiar with shutdown ordering. But in general requirements and ordering are independent of each other so this settings  combination should not be a problem.

Comment: I executed `systemctl start path.service` to verify the there is nothing wrong with the script. I am not sure why its in inactive state